# How to concatenate two videos using ffmpeg with audio added and also I need fede-effcts not cross fade

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, fadein, fadeout

I used following two ffmpeg commands two achieve my task .

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fade=in:0:40,fade=out:92:40"  file1.mp4  //for fade effects

//for concat result of above videos

> ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file1.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v]  [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output-file2.mp4

Now I need single command for both operations with audio supported.
I don't know how to do it in single command. If anyone know, please help me to resolve this.

I tried couple of ffmpeg commands but I faced some audio issues .

thanks in advance.

Comment: I can provide a generic example, but an accurate answer cannot be provided without seeing the complete console output from your second command.

Comment: well i got answer for above question ,here is the command  "
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0]fade=in:0:100,fade=out:980:86[v1];[1:0]fade=in:0:100,fade=out:910:65[v2]; [v1][0:1][v2][1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]'-y output-file2.mp4"

Comment: i just merged two commands

Comment: i have another question .can we add fade-effects to video and generate it to '.ts' file ? . i need it in single command.